JavaScript file not found when HTML and JS are in separate directories
I've created a simple TS project with the following file structure:
dairyproducts.github.io/
├── package.json
├── public/
│   ├── images/
│   ├── index.html
├── src/
│   └── index.ts
├── dist/
│   └── index.js
└── tsconfig.json

Where index.js is the compiled index.ts. The .ts file contains a single hello world console log.
In index.html I have the following line in my header tag:
<script src="../dist/index.js"></script>
Starting the server with http-server and opening the index.html file throws a 404 error for GET /dist/index.js.
However, moving index.js to the public folder and changing the script tag source to "index.js" makes it run perfectly fine. Moving index.js to the root folder and making the source ../index.js doesn't work though.
To my understanding, ../ is supposed to refer to the directory above the current directory, so I don't know why this wouldn't work.
Update: http-server ./ -p 8080 --cors serves a file directory of the root folder, and when the public folder is navigated to the HTML file loads the index.js as expected. I guess the problem now is just finding a way to make the "entry point" of the server public/index.html while still serving from root.

Don't use paths relative to the current directory (ie. ../../../foo/bar.js), use paths relative to the root (ie. /foo/bar.js). Then it does not matter what directory the current file is being executed within

Where is this dist folder you're referencing?  Does that folder contain the output of building the project?  Are you running index.html from that folder, or from this public folder?  It looks like you're showing us the pre-build source code but are referencing the post-build deployable result, and that you're confusing the two.

Don't confuse directories and URL paths. The <script src> is evaluated by the browser relative to the URL of the index.html page, which you have not told us. If it is http://server.com/index.html, then going upwards with ../ makes no sense. You should show us the code of the http-server that serves these files.

@David my apologies, I've fixed the file structure.

@RoryMcCrossan /dist/index.js doesn't work either.

If the site is being served from public/ it will make it impossible to refer to anything from outside that "root" folder.

If the website is being served from the public folder then it would imply that src or dist are inaccessible

I would assume the contents of the public folder should get copied into dist by your bundle. Once this works as desired, the right way would be just /index.js

@dairy: How exactly are you building and/or running your code?

@David To compile the ts I just run tsc from the root folder, and I've configured the tsconfig.json such that "outDir": "./dist" and "rootDir": "./src". I configured the script "start": "http-server -p 8080 --cors ." in package.json and I'm using npm run.

You can only import your assets like CSS  or JavaScript files directly when that files are on the location of public.
Please press F12 key, and just see the source field, can you find the dist folder, maybe you can not.
That's why you can't access that file.
So, please check it is located in your public folder.

This is very likely because your local http-server uses public folder as its root. When index.html is opened in the browser it appears at the root level, and any relative URL starting with ../ makes no sense.
Practically, everything outside public folder is unavaliable from within browser in this scenario.

Edit
There are some pieces to puzzle why the command 
http-server -p 8080 --cors . 
did not work.

http-server sets the root path to ./public when the path
is not specified AND public folder exists (see details here).
--cors is not just a flag but may be followed by list of
headers. So the last . from the command is recognized as a custom
header, effectively leaving the root unspecified.

As a result, the server is started with public folder as its root.
How to fix this?
Start the server with command  http-server ./ -p 8080 --cors  and access the document from  http://localhost:8080/public/index.html.

The start script is http-server -p 8080 --cors . Does it serve from public by default?

This works, but is there a way to serve from the root while keeping the http://localhost:8080/ serve index.html? Or should I just move index.html into the root folder, or is that not a good practice?

There is no way to serve index.html from root level and have scripts in outer directory. You should probably configure build process to make compiled scripts end up below root HTML in the directory structure.

I got it. I'll move the index.html to the outermost root directory and serve from that directory. That makes http://localhost:8080/ serve index.html and allows access to compiled scripts in dist. Or I'll move the dist folder into public. Or I'll copy the contents of public to dist and work from there.
